# whats wrong with my this php update record form

Tags: php

hi here is my code,

```
<html> 
 <?php
  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = '*******';
  $dbpass = '*******';
  $connec = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
  if(!$connec)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  $sql = "UPDATE subscribers SET unsubscribed = '0' WHERE email = '$email'";
  mysql_select_db('********');

if (!mysql_query($sql, $connec))
{

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

echo "1 record added";



mysql_close($connec)
?> 
<form method="post" name="update" action="removal.php">
<input type="text" name="email" value="email" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" />
</form>

</html>
```

WHAT I WANT : I want to show the echo message only after when i submit the form.

PROBLEM : IT shows a echo message after i refresh the page without form submit,

Comment: please do not use mysql_* functions because they're deprecated. Use mysqli_* or even better PDO

Comment: Have you used a tutorial, of did you write this script yourself? $email isn't set, mysql_close isn't usually necessary.

Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put  `if(isset($_POST)){` check: use the below code

```
   <html> 
     <?php
if(isset($_POST)){
      $dbhost = 'localhost';
      $dbuser = '*******';
      $dbpass = '*******';
      $connec = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
      if(!$connec)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
      $sql = "UPDATE subscribers SET unsubscribed = '0' WHERE email = '$email'";
      mysql_select_db('********');

    if (!mysql_query($sql, $connec))
    {

      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

      }

    echo "1 record added";



    mysql_close($connec)
}
    ?>
```

Comment: no  nothing displayed in page after i update the code to this

Comment: You need to put form also below this code and when you click on submit this will work

Answer (score 1):

> IT shows a echo message after i refresh the page without form submit

That's normal because once the script is called, nothing blocks the interpreter from executing the code, all you have to do is to check first whether there is a submitted from or not

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
  {
    // your code here
  }
?>
```

Also, note that in the following line:
`$sql = "UPDATE subscribers SET unsubscribed = '0' WHERE email = '$email'";`
you are using `$email` without initializing it, you should first copy the form email entry to the variable and use it later

Answer (score 1):

Add this before your SQL statement

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['email'])){
   // write post processing code here 
}
```

Comment: wrong answer, this will not stop executing the entire form processing code

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
if (!mysql_query($sql, $connec)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "1 record added";
}
```

Comment: no its not working, the problem was that when i load that page, it shows the echo when i load page, but i want it shows an echo only when i submit the form

Comment: i see. then the "if(isset($_POST))" comments are correct